# Excel check if any 2 values within the same row equal any others

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data which has 6 columns and tens of thousands of rows.
I need to count the number of times a given row shares data from column B and E with a different row's columns B and E.

For example,
`COUNTIF(AND(B[X]=B[Y],E[X]=B[Y]))`

```
    A         B            C       D                   E            F
1  6725  555-371-7295   0:00:12 Answered    10/8/2012 8:57  outbound
2  6725  555-371-7295   0:00:31 Answered    10/8/2012 8:57  outbound
3  6714  555-558-2100   0:00:13 Answered    10/8/2012 8:59  outbound
4  6714  555-558-2100   0:00:25 Answered    10/8/2012 9:08  outbound
5  6725  555-842-2600   0:00:04 Answered    10/8/2012 9:08  outbound
```

where X and Y are row numbers

The code above is obviously not real Excel code, it's just supposed to get across what I'm looking to do. Notice that B1=B2 AND E1 = E2 that's what I'm looking to count. B3 = B4 but E3 <> E4 so I would not want to count that.

This means, COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,E:E,E1) won't work because what I really need is `COUNTIFS(B1:B5,ANY B1:B5,El:E5, ANY El:E5)` I hope I made the question is somewhat clear.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starts in row 1, you can use this as your first formula:

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,E:E,E1)-1`

Comment: Good job on the -1, but it looks like th eend should be `E:E,B1)`.

Comment: Not sure about that as the text of the question differs from the pseudo-formula.

Comment: @Gimp To use `-1` or not depends on if the OP want to count two equal rows as `2 rows` or `1 repeated row`.  The OP is not clear which is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, you can use t`COUNTIFS`, which allows for more than one criteria

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,E:E,B1)
```

If using Excel 2003 use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$1000=A1)*($B$1:$B$1000=A1))
```

As an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Adjust ranges `A1:A1000` and `B:B1000` to suit.

Comment: You can't use whole columns in SUMPRODUCT in Excel 2003 or earlier versions Chris - you'd need to restrict the range for the 2003 version